# jenkins cookbook Issue

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra

Anyone encountered below error and how to overcome it

#### Jenkins Cookbook version

6.0.0

#### Chef-client version

12.4.3

#### Platform Details

RHEL 7

#### Steps to Reproduce:

Error executing action `create` on resource `jenkins_user[robot]`

```
Begin output of "java" -jar "/var/chef/cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s  http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ -"remoting" groovy = ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: ERROR: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission
---- End output of "java" -jar "/var/chef/cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s 
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ -"remoting" groovy = ----
```

How to set Jenkins User to install Plugins and Jobs?

Comment: IRC you have to create administrator user using jenkins_script resource. Anonymous remoting is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at executor [attributes](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/master/attributes/executor.rb), you can see that default CLI protocol is set as remoting. Previously jenkins was showing allowing remote option as a security warning. But now it is disabled by default. You can verify this if you go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security. You won't be able to use any jenkins cookbook resources if you use remote option since that is disabled in settings. Well you can manually enable remoting option but that is not advisable

The fix is to use either http or ssh protocol. ssh is more secured. Look at this [discussion](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/issues/599) on how to use ssh protocol (given towards the end). You should be good to use jenkins cookbook resources after this

Comment: See also the documentation about authentication to expand on what @slashpai mentioned. https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins#authentication